# Reading SharePoint Document Library File names using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I am trying to read the file names from SharePoint document library. I have uploaded some files and created some folders on the site. I get the ItemCount number. But when i try to get the File count or Folder count it shows 0.
It's not traversing into the foreach loop. Any answer would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
   using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'><Query></Query></View>";
            Folder ff = list.RootFolder;

            FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
            List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();

            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
            clientContext.Load(ff);
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Response.Write("Root : " + ff.Name+"\r\n");
            Response.Write( " ItemCount : " + ff.ItemCount.ToString() );
            Response.Write( " Folder Count : " + ff.Folders.Count.ToString() );
            Response.Write( " File Count : " + ff.Files.Count.ToString());
            Response.Write( " URL : " + ff.ServerRelativeUrl );

            foreach (Folder f in fcol)
            {
                if (f.Name == "Testing")
                {
                    clientContext.Load(f.Files);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;
                    foreach (File file in fileCol)
                    {
                        lstFile.Add(file.Name);
                        Response.Write(" File Name : " + file.Name);
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: I used your code in a console application, and it worked for me.  Are you sure you have folders and files in said library?

Comment: Your camlQuery variable is declared and then set, but you never do anything with it (ie 'ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery);')

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery()` instead of using your Caml Query there?

Comment: It worked for me, I forgot to add connection in APPManifest file. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to read all the subfolders and nested folders and files from SharePoint document library.

Comment: You need a recursive method. It returns `void` and takes in a `Folder` parameter. You do your work on the parameter being passed in. You then need to `load` and `ExecuteQuery` on the `Folders` property. You then do a `foreach` over the `Folders` property, and within that you call the method that you're in, passing in the current iterator.

To see example code of this, see here: http://pastebin.com/Vac3zyF8

Comment: With same reference, how to get file names from Zip folder without extracting it. I have files, folder and zip folder in the document library. I am unable to get the file names from zip folder.

Comment: A zip folder isn't a folder, it's a compressed file. You'll need to use server side code with some third party libraries to extract and inspect the file.

Comment: Yes I am using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip; And I am able to get the zip file name but not able to get the files into the zip file. string filePath = Page.Request["SPHostUrl"] + file.ServerRelativeUrl;
                ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath));
                ZipEntry item;
                while ((item = zip.GetNextEntry()) != null)
                {
                    Response.Write(item.Name);
                }

Comment: Here, I am getting exception of file doesn't exist. But File exits. I have given full path of SharePoint Document Library. But any how it takes path of local drive i.e. C:// that's why it says file doesn't exist. How to give path of SharePoint document library.

Comment: I get exception as : The given path's format is not supported. I get this path in filepath: "https://showmesoftlabs.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/ZIP.zip "  File exist on that path. But the path format is not allowed. If I don't give full path then it takes local drive path i.e. from C://

Comment: SharpZipLib won't load files from a URI, only a local path. If you can open the file using `SPFile.OpenBinaryStream()` you may be able to pass that into SharpZipLib.

Comment: I need to use only CSOM.